# Huge size of /lib/modules/3.19.3 while building custom kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I was building Linux 3.19.3 for my Linux Mint 64-bit laptop, and ran out of space because of a huge `/lib/modules/3.19.3` folder.

I used the config file for 3.16.0-31-generic that was supplied by my Mint updates, reverting to default for any new parameters.

Size of `/lib/modules` for various kernels:

```
184M    /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic
193M    /lib/modules/3.15.0-031500-generic
191M    /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic
192M    /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic
4.0K    /lib/modules/3.16.1-031601-generic
2.3G    /lib/modules/3.19.3
608K    /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic
```

And this size is despite `make modules_install` being interrupted due to lack of disk space.

Even some of the older kernels listed here were custom compiled. Is there any parameter I'm missing?

Link to .config - http://paste.ubuntu.com/10726888/

Comment: Why don't you look and see if something particular is big?  Why not grep all the lines set as module out of the respective configs and wc them?

Comment: It seems all modules are larger. ``fs/btrfs/btrfs.ko`` in 3.16.0-29 is 1.4MB, while the same module in 3.19.3 is 16MB. The number of files seems similar - 3562 files in the interrupted 3.19 vs 4150 files in the full 3.16.

Comment: diff the configs maybe you have something extra in the way of debug turned on that bloats everything.  Or maybe the build system is broken and failing to do some sensible stripping or whatever.

Comment: Problem is solved if you run ``strip --strip-unneeded`` on each ``.ko`` file (source: http://serverfault.com/questions/323716/linux-kernel-module-file-size). Is there a way to specify this while building the kernel?

Comment: Well, you build with debuginfo (`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`), that is why it is not stripping.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I wonder why it was set in the configs that came from Mint's repositories in the first place.